# .htaccess rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want it so that any swf media in a directory gets redirected to a file like

```
http://website.com/swf.php?d=file
```

Then threw http access, change the link above to

```
http://website.com/file
```

so lets assume I have the file

```
http://website.com/thisvideo.swf
```

I want it to redirect to
http://website.com/swf.php?d=thisvideo.swf

BUT with .htaccess change the above link to 
    http://website.com/thisvideo.swf

So when they visit thisvideo.swf it doesnt go to the direct swf but the php file with the query in it (assuming thats hidden via the .htaccess).

I hope you get what im trying to say, but I don't know how to do the first step of redirecting if its swf, or rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.swf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /virtual/path/to/script.php?d=$1 [NC,L]
```

This basically says "take any URL with a `.swf` extension, keep its URL the same (mask it), and forward the request to `script.php`.

Edit: if you want to be strict about it, you could add the following immediately below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

which will force it only to rewrite valid files (eg, you wouldn't be redirecting any 404's).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*\.swf)$ /swf.php?d=$1 [QSA,L]
```